# How can I fix not all arguments converted during string formatting?

Tags: python, numpy

I want to change some binary streams to decimal but I got **not all arguments converted during string formatting**. The point is I have the result when using `binaryToDecimal (10100000)` which `10100000` is the first value of my list. But when I use `binaryToDecimal (instream_chunks[0])` which is my `for` loop I got the above error. How can I fix that?
I am new to python sorry for my simple question.......

```
def binaryToDecimal(binary):
      
    binary1 = binary
    decimal, i, n = 0, 0, 0
    while(binary != 0):
        dec = binary % 10
        decimal = decimal + dec * pow(2, i)
        binary = binary//10
        i += 1
    print(decimal)
    
    instream = '1010000000011000000110000000001'

    instream_chunks = [instream[i:i+8]for i in range (0, len(instream), 8)]

for i in range (len(instream_chunks)):
    
     img_value = binaryToDecimal (instream_chunks[i])
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to convert the strings to integers before using your function on them. Like so:

```
def binaryToDecimal(binary):
      
    binary1 = binary
    decimal, i, n = 0, 0, 0
    while(binary != 0):
        dec = binary % 10
        decimal = decimal + dec * pow(2, i)
        binary = binary//10
        i += 1
    print(decimal)
    
instream = '1010000000011000000110000000001'

instream_chunks = [instream[i:i+8]for i in range (0, len(instream), 8)]

for i in range (len(instream_chunks)):
     img_value = binaryToDecimal (int(instream_chunks[i]))
```